# Failed to get open extension when use delta

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using Microsoft Graph. First I added open extension to mail by

```
POST /me/messages/{messageId}/extensions

{
  "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
  "extensionName": "myExtension",
  "virtualId": "12345"
}
```

Then I can successfully get those mails with extensions by

```
GET /me/mailfolders/SentItems/messages?$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'myExtension')
```

But I failed to get when I use delta by

```
GET /me/mailfolders/SentItems/messages/delta?$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'myExtension')
```

It gives me error:

> ```
> {
>     "error": {
>         "code": "InternalServerError",
>         "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type",
>         "innerError": {
>             "request-id": "89f54294-b49b-410b-99d0-0c2df9d90f1d",
>             "date": "2017-11-20T04:50:57"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

How to get open extension when use delta?

Comment: Does it change the behavior if you specifically `$select` your extension? I know this is an issue with Schema Extensions but I'm not sure if Open Extensions are also affected.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur no it does not help, tried `/me/mailfolders/SentItems/messages/delta?$select=subject&$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'myExtension')`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I meant including `extensions` in the `$select`:  `$select=subject,extensions&$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'myExtension')`.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur no, same error, tried `/me/mailfolders/SentItems/messages/delta?$select=subject,extensions&$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'myExtension')`

Comment: I don't think that delta query supports open extensions (or schema extensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered this via email, but posting here as well to close the loop. We do not support delta query on open extension properties today. This is something we want to support in the future, but we don't have specific plans yet.